# R: Obtaining the average of numeric variables while the max for binary variables in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataset:

```
Lines <- "id time sex Age A
1  1       male   90 0
1  2       male   91 0
1  3       male   92 1
2  1       female  87 0
2  2       female  88 0
2  3       female  89 0
3  1       male  50 0
3  2       male  51 1
3  3       male  52 0
4  1       female  54 0
4  2       female  55 0
4  3       female  56 0"
```

I would like to obtain the mean value for the numeric variable and the highest value for the binary variables (e.g. if 0 and 1, then 1). And for the string variables, just the name as this does not vary across id.

The resulting data frame should be something like this:

```
Lines <- "id time sex Age A
1  2       male   91 1
2  2       female  88 0
3  2       male  51 1
4  2       female  55 0"
```

I have more or less an idea:

```
Lines <- Lines %>%
    group_by(id, across(where(is.character))) %>%
    summarise(across(where(all(column %in% 0:1)), max)) %>%
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean)) %>%
    ungroup
```

Comment: should be the mean as well for the variable time :)

Comment: Also, is the "binarity" of a field dynamically determined, or do you know it ahead of time?  That is, do you know ahead of time that there will be a binary field `A` containing only the values `0` and `1`?  If so, I see no reason to perform checks like `where(all(column %in% 0:1)`, and so forth, unless the schema is so ponderous that it would be a pain to individually `mutate` each column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought about using `across` function to apply `mean` on only numeric variables in one try, but I noticed they are actually stored as `integer` as well as your binary variable. So we either have to change their classes before our solution and use `across` or explicitly name every variable like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(id = first(id), sex = first(sex), time = mean(time), 
            Age = mean(Age), A = max(A))

# A tibble: 4 x 5
     id sex     time   Age     A
  <int> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1 male       2    91     1
2     2 female     2    88     0
3     3 male       2    51     1
4     4 female     2    55     0
```

Here is another solution, however I coerced some variables into classes mentioned in the question before applying our transformation. It would be a good idea if you could do it too:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(across(c(time, Age), as.numeric)) %>%
  summarise(id = first(id), sex = first(sex), 
            across(where(is.integer), max, .names = "{.col}"),
            across(where(is.double), mean, .names = "{.col}"))

# A tibble: 4 x 5
     id sex        A  time   Age
  <int> <chr>  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 male       1     2    91
2     2 female     0     2    88
3     3 male       1     2    51
4     4 female     0     2    55
```

Comment: great answer thanks, do you think there is a more extrapolate solution that does not require defining each variable?

Comment: @Economist_Ayahuasca Yes but we have to coerce each variable into the classes defined in the question. I will post a more another solution.